# Download PDF from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, download

I have searched for answers and it seems everything is asp.net and webforms.

I'm trying to find an entity/MVC solution I have to assume they are similar.

I have a database which has the info for the file stored in SQL Server datatype `Image`. I already have all the code to attach to files to the right people as needed. The only thing I am missing is how to build the `Download` link.

The HTML View will look like this.

The information about the document will be in a table containing information like document name, type etc.  It will also have a `Download` link.  Once they click this link I would like to have the file served to them for download.

This is the part that escapes me when doing it in MVC. I have the document in a model `incoming_file` is the column that contains the document.

How do I force the download of everything in `incoming_file` when they click `Download`?

Comment: Return a FileResult with the pdf stream https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult(v=vs.118).aspx with the PDF mime type (application/pdf).  Easy peasy.  Give it a whirl.

Comment: The `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @marc_s it's a database from a third party with log shipping, so it isn't something that we can edit.

Comment: Then tell that third-party to clean up their act! :-)